# I want my button to navigate back to my home page not to the immediate previous page in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I want my flutter app to navigate from my last screen back to the home page. Currently, it navigates back to the previous page which I do not want.

```
onPressed: () {
    Navigator.pop(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()));
                      },
```

I expect the button to return me back to the Home Page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use named routes you can simply replace your code with this:

```
onPressed: () {
   Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
},
```

This will pop the navigation stack until it reaches the first item which might be your home page.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use Navigator.pushAndReplace(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage())); for navigation back to the home page?

Comment: tried that now and it underlined red saying: method push and replace isnt assigned for Navigator

Comment: Can you take a screendump or copy the exact error message?

Comment: The method 'pushAndReplace' isn't defined for the class 'Navigator'.

Comment: Try to use this: Navigator.pushReplacement() - This will make your push the frontpage, but replace it so it replaces the other activity in the stack.